# OMS extension or Windows Diagnostics extension

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics

Can the windows diagnostic do the same as the OMS extension in terms of getting performance counter information and event details? Is there a reason to use the OMS extension over WAD for event/performance information?

Answer (score 1):

> Can the windows diagnostic do the same as the OMS extension in terms
>   of getting performance counter information and event details?

**WAD:** This uses Azure Diagnostics agent for single VM.

**OMS:** When you use OMS to  monitor your VM or multiple Vs, The OMS collect data from Microsoft Monitoring Agent by default. However, OMS can collect data from managed resources into a central repository. This data could include events, performance data, or custom data provided through the API. So, OMS can also use the WAD's data through the storage account which contains the agent's data.

So, **OMS has more features than WAD.** Also as [@4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) said, if you want to monitor one VM, WAD is enough to achieve that.

> Is there a reason to use the OMS extension over WAD for
>   event/performance information?

OMS focus on **collecting data from different place and Log Analytics**.

It can collect data from Windows/Linux VMs, Azure services and Data Collector API.

Reporting and analyzing data is the most important feature of OMS. Alerting can also be configured in OMS.

Azure Automation provides process automation and configuration management to OMS.

[image]

Over all, if you want to do Analytics from multiple service, OMS is the best choice. If you only want to monitor a single VM rather doing other things, WAD is enough.

Comment: Hi, @Dave N . If this answer is helpful to you , please accept it as answer so that we can help more communities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at performance from one vm - no.
but there is a chance you have more than one vm oms extension suddenly gets more interesting, as you can look at all of the vms at the same time, setup alerts, actions etc.